# C++ constructors in subclass

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism

I want to send my constructor `Buttom(string)` from my derived to the function `setText(string)` in my base , I tried to do this

```
Buttom(string) : setText(string text){}
```

... which gives me the following syntax error:

> Syntax error - expected primary-expression before ‘text’ - class ‘Buttom’ does not have any field named ‘setText’

base class:

```
#include"RGB.h"
#include"Point.h"
#include"string"
using namespace std;
class Widget{
protected:
    RGB _backgroundColor,_textColor;
    Point _position;
    int _width,_heigth;
    string _text;
public:
    Widget();
    Widget(const Widget&);
    virtual ~Widget();
    void setBackgroundColor(const RGB&);
    RGB getBackgroundColor() const;
    void setTextColor(const RGB&);
    RGB getColor() const;
    void setPosition(const Point&);
    Point getPosition() const;
    void setWidth(int);
    int getWidth() const;
    void setHeigth(int);
    int getHeigth() const;
    void setText(string text);
    string getText() const;
    bool isPointInWidget(Point&) const;
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
    virtual Widget& operator=(const Widget&) = 0;
    virtual bool operator==(const Widget&) = 0;

};
```

derived class:

```
#include"string"
#include"Widget.h"
class Buttom : public Widget{
public:
    Buttom();
    Buttom(string);
    Buttom(const Buttom&);
    ~Buttom();
    void draw() const;
    Widget& operator=(const Widget&);
    bool operator==(const Widget&);

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Buttom(string) : setText(string text){}
> ```

You cannot invoke a class member function this way, using the class member initializer list.

You can invoke it in the constructor's body instead, as follows:

```
Buttom(string s) : Widget() { 
    setText(s); 
}
```

Comment: How could you possible know that this is the problem from the information in the question?

Comment: From what the op said, it's very likely this is the solution.

Comment: @aslg Nope, there's plenty of other reasons of failure left. There's not even a clear error message specified.

Comment: By looking at the code he put in his request I tried to figure out which is his problem. It looks pretty obvious to me, for his code is wrong and the intent quite clear.

Comment: @skypjack I can't even see a good match for the classes named in the OP and your answer. This needs to be seriously improved, to be of any value.

Comment: in your code you call base with string i cant do in my case, please have a look i edited my post @skypjack

Comment: Changed nothing but a couple of names. ;-)